# Why "from googletrans import Translator" is not working in Atom text editor

Tags: python, atom-editor, google-translation-api

So I have recently installed Atom text editor on my UNIX machine and tried to run this simple Google API's translator program but it's giving me an "ImportError: No module named googletrans". I have already installed googletrans in bash console through pip and this same program is giving me a desired output in IDLE but I want to make to it work in ATOM as well. Do I have to install any kind of package or something in ATOM in order for this to work? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
translations = translator.translate(['The quick brown fox', 'jumps 
over', 'the lazy dog'], dest='hi')
for translation in translations:
    print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
```

Comment: Is Atom using the python installed in your console or did it come with its own python installation? If your script works in bash, then Atom seems to use a different python installation, so it is not effected by pip-installed packages in your console.

Comment: Atom has its own little python console where it is showing me the error message. I am not sure what version of python atom is running. I think my problem has something to do with adding the python to Atom path for execution and I don't know how to do that. I could be wrong tho.